# problem with understanding these equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've come across these equations while reading a scheduling book. Because I am not very good with mathematics  I would be grateful if you could help me to interpret and understand these equations (the overall idea)

**Equation 1**

$$F= \{i | \sum_{1 \le j \le k}  X_{ij}p_{j }= min _{ 1 \le g \le m} \{ \sum_{1 \le j \le k} X_{gj}p_{j} \}\}$$

**Equation 2**

$$ R_{l}(T_{t}) \le m_{l} - \sum_{1 \le j \le k} R_{l}(T_{j}) |  \{ g| Z_{g} = j \} | $$ $$ l = 1,2,...,s$$

$T_j$ is the task j, $R_l$ is the resource requirement so $R_l(T_j)$ means the resource requirement of task j. $Z_g$ is a vector where each of its element is the task recently assigned to a machine. I would like to know what does this portion means  $|  \{ g| Z_{g} = j \} | $

Comment: The first one is giving you the index (or indices) of the vector coordinate which is the lowest. Suppose $\mathbf{p}$ a vector and $X$ a matrix, then multiplying $X\mathbf{p}$ results in a *transformed* vector. $F$ contains the index of the lowest value. If the transformed vector is like $(0, 3,5)$ then $F=\{1\}$, whereas if the transformed vector is like $(1,4,1)$ then $F=\{1,3\}$. Then second equation is less clear. how is $R_\ell$ defined? (how is $Z_g, T_i, \ldots$ defined?)

Comment: Thank you dietervdf, 

Now I understand that **$min _{ 1 \le g \le m} \{ \sum_{1 \le j \le k} X_{gj}p_{j} \}$** means that will it return the min value of the of the transformed vector.
I would like to know what does the equation on the left hand side of the assignment do, i.e this equation **$\sum_{1 \le j \le k}  X_{ij}p_{j }$**.

I have added more details regarding $R_{l}$ etc.. in my main post